# Redshift: Find results NOT IN each previous grouping?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have a table generated by the following script:

`first_date as ( select a.id , a.text , a.date , min(a.date) over (partition by hashed_id) dt_min , dense_rank() over (partition by a.hashed_id order by a.date) denserank)`

ID is for users, text indicates which page they visited, date is when, dt_min is their first visit and Denserank shows the order of visits a user took to a site.

I'm able to show how many pages they visited per visit with this:

`select id , denserank , count(text) from first_date fd group by 1, 2;`

...but what I'm trying to do is show how many pages they saw per visit which they *hadn't seen on previous visits*.

I'm sure I could do it manually and create a huge where clause or series of CASE statements which filtered separately on the various visits, so visit 2 = NOT IN visit 1, visit 3 = NOT IN visit 1,2 etc, etc, but this seems way more labor-intensive than it needs to be.

Does anyone have any pointers for solving this one in a more efficient way?

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help immensely

Comment: Make it a cte table, then join it to itself, so for each row, join the rows with lower ids, then you can use the count of those rows or something to answer your question.